# Is the (Holman) Christian Standard Bible's rendering, "completely dark sheep", at Gen. 30:40, reasonably correct?

Tags: genesis, translation-philosophy

Is the (Holman) Christian Standard Bible's rendering, "completely dark sheep", at Gen. 30:40, reasonably correct?

> Jacob separated the lambs and made the flocks face the streaked sheep and the completely dark sheep in Laban’s flocks. Then he set his own stock apart and didn’t put them with Laban’s sheep.

Answer (score 1):

חוּם (*chum*) means “brown.” Dark refers to the hue of a color. The Hebrew word for “dark” is כֵּהֶה (*kehe*). Thus, “dark brown” is חוּם כֵּהֶה (*chum kehe*), “dark blue” is כָּחֹל כֵּהֶה (*kachol kehe*), etc. The opposite of כֵּהֶה is בָּהִיר (*bahir*). Thus, “light brown” is חוּם בָּהִיר (*chum bahir*), “light blue” is כָּחֹל בָּהִיר (*kachol bahir*), etc.

“Black” would be שָׁחֹר (*shachor*).

You can find the names of Hebrew colors in a variety of places on the internet.<sup>1</sup> However, for the word in question:<sup>2</sup>

[image]

#### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> For example: https://www.hebrewpod101.com/hebrew-vocabulary-lists/talking-about-colors/
<sup>2</sup> Josephs, p. [35](https://books.google.com/books?id=G-lGAAAAcAAJ&pg=PP344#v=onepage&q&f=true)

#### References

Josephs, Michael. [*An English and Hebrew Lexicon.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=G-lGAAAAcAAJ) London: Wertheim: 1834.

Comment: What about the lamb?